# How do I enable syntax highlighting in PowerShell Core?

Tags: powershell, syntax-highlighting, powershell-core

I have recently installed [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell) through [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/packages/powershell-core).

My newly installed PowerShell Core doesn't have syntax highlighting (red circles in the screenshot below) nor does it append the backslash `\` when auto-completing directories (blue circles in the screenshot below).

[image: New PowerShell Core vs old PowerShell]

How do I enable both this features in the new PowerShell Core?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open your PowerShell profile (e.g. `~\Documents\PowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1`)
2. Append the line `Import-Module PSReadLine`

If you are using multiple keyboard layouts and have PSReadLine version 2.0.0 installed, due to [this bug](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSReadLine/issues/854), you need to install the [latest beta](https://github.com/PowerShell/PSReadLine/releases) with:

```
Install-Module -Name PSReadLine -RequiredVersion 2.0.0-beta5 -AllowPrerelease
```

Documentation:

- [Understanding the Six PowerShell Profiles](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/understanding-the-six-powershell-profiles/)
- [Use PSReadLine for More Efficient PowerShell Console](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-psreadline-for-more-efficient-powershell-console/)